# User prompt using if statements

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user if they are pregnant. The problem I'm having is if the person enters "maybe" or any other response than "yes" or "no" I want the program to say "It's a yes or no question" then prompt the user to answer the question again. Instead it prints " It's a yes or no question" and "are you pregnant? " but it cannot accept another response. Is this the correct format for what I'm trying to do? In other words I want my program to keep asking the user if she is pregnant until I get a yes or no answer.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class AskProgram extends ConsoleProgram{
    public void run(){

        String answer = readLine(" are you pregnant? ");

        if (answer.equals("yes")) {
            println("Great! Congratulations ");
        } else if (answer.equals("no")) {
            println("keep trying it will happen."); 
        } else {
            println("Its a yes or no question");
            readline("are you pregnant? ");
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: Place the code in a `while` loop, set the exit condition on yes or no answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will repeat the block until the user inputs either "Yes" or "No":

```
String answer = "";
while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
    answer = readLine("Are you pregnant?");
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        println("Great! Congratulations ");
        break;
    } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        println("keep trying it will happen."); 
        break;
    } else {
        println("Its a yes or no question");
        readline("are you pregnant? ");
    }    
}
```

Comment: +1 didn't see your answer before i posted mine, deleting mine.

Comment: @Alex23 is a while loop the only way it can be done? Can it be done with if statements?

Comment: @JessicaM. it would be goto, which is both really ugly/unreadable and notexistent in java.

Comment: Try answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") and answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no") so the user won't be wrong if they capitalize it

Comment: @Alex23 Still studying the code a little bit. I've run into a small problem. If the user enters "maybe" the program says "it's a yes or no question" then asks the user again "are you pregnant" as expected. So far so good. But if the user enters "yes" I expect the program to print "Great!  Congratulations" but instead it prints "are you pregnant" again instead. If you enter "yes" to that question it then prints "Great! Congratulations."  In other words to get "Great! Congratulations" the user has to enter the series "maybe" "yes" "yes" vs. "maybe" "yes". Sorry if that's a little but confusing.

Answer (score -1):

This is a version using recursion (and a return value):

```
private static boolean isPregnant() {
    String answer = readLine("Are you pregnant?");
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        println("Great! Congratulations ");
        return true;
    } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        println("keep trying it will happen.");
        return false;
    } else {
        println("It's a yes or no question");
        return isPregnant();
    }

}
```

Comment: This function should really return a boolean or a string to indicate what the result was! (I didn't downvote btw).

Comment: The only other thing I would change, I wouldn't print the "great.." or "keep trying..." strings inside this function - that should be done in the function that calls this one. That way you can re-use this function later if you need to and don't want those strings printed, if you know what I mean :)

Comment: @Mareser Thanks for your input. I don't know why it got down voted but thanks.